# Excel add VBA code to Worksheet functions of newly created worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

My source data in CSV file has one column with the HYPERLINK formula which I would like to use via a Pivot Table - I create a Pivot Table from the source data, after I click the Pivot Table to create a new worksheet with the selected data I can go to the new worksheet and click the cell with the hyperlink and go to the website directly

I suppose it is a known limitation that formulas in the source data will *NOT* populate to the new worksheet. Is there anyway to populate the hyperlink?

I have explore to see if I can add some VBA code to detect if the cells with hyperlink has been selected - via the `Worksheet_ChangeSelection` function. However, the worksheet will be created via the Pivot Table click and I couldn't find a way to link the code to the worksheet before it is even created.

I have also tried to see if Workbook function can do this but still not able to find the missing link.

Any help or pointer would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "*a way to link the code to the worksheet before it is even created*" this is impossible. Also you cannot add VBA code to a CSV file. Therefore you must import a CSV file and save as XLSM first before you can use VBA. Then you could loop through the worksheet and add the hyperlinks using the [`Hyperlinks.Add()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/hyperlinks-add-method-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You would then have to start your procedure manually once you imported the data.

Comment: Actually if you open a csv file Excel is perfectly happy to add a vba module to it without saving it first. - it just won't save the vba without it being an xls or xlsm file type.